# Lock iPad into single folder view with pdf files

Tags: ipad, pdf

I have a requirement, to have an iPad locked to a single folder view, with 1 level subfolders, each with a list of pdf files:

```
.
├── Bob Dylan/
│   ├── file1.pdf
│   ├── file2.pdf
│   ├── file3.pdf
│   └── file4.pdf
├── Eric Clapton/
│   ├── file1.pdf
│   ├── file2.pdf
│   ├── file3.pdf
│   └── file4.pdf
└── Led Zeppelin/
    ├── file1.pdf
    ├── file2.pdf
    ├── file3.pdf
    └── file4.pdf
```

I think of some pdf viewer which can allow one to create this tree, so that when iPad is locked into that app, one can only browser this simple tree and open these files, and nothing else.

So tried a number of pdf readers, but still did not meet the one which does it.

As I'm not native to Apple ecosystem, and not an Apple user myself, I thought maybe someone happens to know an appropriate app for this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Instead of looking for an app, how about setting up a website with the desired structure and locking Safari into One app mode with the said website open? If your iPad is going to stay in a premise, you can also choose to host the website locally and do away with requiring Internet connectivity.

Comment: It doesn't even need to be a full-fledged website. Just files hosted on a server can also do.

Comment: @NimeshNeema thanks. I'll definetly look the keyboard, but what if someone will enter different site from the browser history?

Comment: If you are okay configuring your iPad this way, you can choose to disable Internet access on the device. An alternate and quite easy solution could be to write an iPad app with nothing but a full-screen WebView, without an address bar, with the locally hosted site open, and your iPad locked into this app in Single app mode.

Comment: You need a specialized directory structure which hopefully no existing app would fulfil on the App Store. It's quite easy to write an app yourself especially for this use case.

Comment: If you wish to go with the option of writing an app, you can also choose to keep the PDF files within the app bundle which will free you from even requiring any kind of network connectivity.

Comment: @NimeshNeema hopefully I'd try the custom app way in a couple of years, but this time I think I can't afford spending the time on that.